# How to find out, which FTP server is installed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ftp

In Windows I can check in `Control Panel -> Programs and Features`, which program is installed for some task:

[image]

Now I want to find out for my Ubuntu `14.04` (VirtualBox VM), whether an / which FTP server is installed on it.

**How to get the information about the installed FTP Server?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> telnet myip 21

If the connection succeeds you have probably a ftp server listening, which will give you a welcome message which usually contains the version. Also, `netstat -nplt` helps to see, what listing sockets you have, something listening on port 21 is usually a FTP server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Both solutions have worked. `netstat -nplt`: I got a list without any entry with `ftp` or port `21`. After I have installed `vsftpd`, the entry `tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:21 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 9428/vsftpd` appears on the list. `telnet MYIP 21` is starting a new FTP connection: `Trying MYIP...
Connected to MYIP.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)`